# How to fix this unsorted array in insertion sort?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

I'm creating an insertion sort, the first one is working and returning a sorted array:

```
// {9, 8, 3, 13, 87, 12, 1, 99} the unsorted list

static int[] insertionSort(int[] a){

    for (int i = 1; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
        int element = a[i];
        int j = i - 1;
        while(j >= 0 && a[j] > element){
            a[j+1] = a[j];
            j--;
        }
        a[j+1] = element;

    }
    return a;
}

// returns {1,3,8,9,12,13,67}
```

but the other one is not due to one problem on the second code by just replacing the "element" by "a[i]" which is the same:

```
// {9, 8, 3, 13, 87, 12, 1, 99} the unsorted list

static int[] insertionSort(int[] a){

    for (int i = 1; i < a.length - 1; i++) {
        int element = a[i]; // what
        int j = i - 1;
        while(j >= 0 && a[j] > a[i]){
            a[j+1] = a[j];
            j--;
        }
        a[j+1] = a[i];

    }
    return a;
}
// returns {9,9,9,13,87,87,87}
```

from what i know a[i] and element is the same.

Comment: you wrote `a[j+1] = a[i]`. Where do you expect to find the value that was at `j+1`after this line?

Comment: They are, but in the first code you are saving a[i] into a different variable, in the second code you are directly using the element inside the array, which is being currently modified by the for loop.

Comment: Exactly what @jhamon said

Comment: in the inner `while` loop the value of `a[i]` can be changed

Comment: @shourav would that solve his issue?  the condition says `a[j] > a[i]`, are you still sure about your statement?

Comment: @jhamon let `j=0`, `i=1` and the input `[9, 8, 3, 13, 87, 12, 1, 99]` for the statement `a[j+1]=a[j]`, `a[1]` will be changed to 9 which was `a[i]`. And I am sure about my statement.

Comment: @jhamon the issue is  when`a[j+1] = a[i];` and a[i] is changed in the inner loop

Comment: my bad, I misunderstood your first comment and though you suggested to replace `a[j]` to `a[i]`, not that the `a[i]` value was actually changed

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this..

```
int [] array = {9, 8, 3, 13, 87, 12, 1, 99};
   Arrays.sort(array);
   for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   System.out.println(array[i]);
   };
```

OR

```
int [] array = {9, 8, 3, 13, 87, 12, 1, 99};
   int temp;
   for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i; j > 0; j--) {
     if (array[j] < array [j - 1]) {
      temp = array[j];
      array[j] = array[j - 1];
      array[j - 1] = temp;
     }
    }
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     System.out.println(array[i]);
   }
```

Comment: While this solution actually sort an array, it seems OP want to write the sort algorithm by himself at not use a built-in method